# how to skip install libphp5.so when buidling php?

Tags: php, configure

I'm trying configure and install older php 5.3 version on my archlinux, and I don't want it to copy `libphp5.so` to `/usr/lib/httpd/modules/` because there's an existing version (newer) there.

```
/usr/share/apr-1/build/libtool --mode=install install libphp5.la /usr/lib/httpd/modules/
libtool: install: install .libs/libphp5.so /usr/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
install: cannot remove '/usr/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so': Permission denied
```

I think there should be a configure flag to control that, can anyone help me?

Comment: Look at the [official installation procedure](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php) from the php manual

Comment: I did, but I can't find where is the part about skip install libphp5.so, could you point me out?

Comment: You can run `./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs; 
make` and skip `make install`.  Everything will be compiled but it won't be moved from the build directory.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are using `--with-apxs2`, you can exclude this option if you don't want to build `libphp5.so`. Omitting the `./configure` options when building PHP will build without a particular feature.

#### References

- [Bug #41576 no way to configure --without-apxs](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=41576)

Comment: I want build libphp5.so, but I don't want to install it to my system